# Where to exactly put asp UpdatePanel control in a form?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I'm new to ASP.NET. I have the following code, but I don't know where to place the asp:UpdatePanel control, its contenttemplate and (if needed) its triggers, so I can have a validation without postback?

```
 <form method="post" id="formLogin" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            // bunch of scriptreferences
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email:"/><br/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password:"/><br/>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>
                </p>

        <div id="msg" runat="server" class="item">

                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
                </div>

                <div class="loginbutton">
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot Password?</a><br />
                        <a href="../EN/form_1.aspx" class="forgot">New user?</a>
                    </p>
                    <input type="reset" name="login" value="Cancel" id="cancel" />

                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
                </div>
    </form>
```

The lblMessage shows up as "You have entered incorrect email/password" if the credentials don't match database records.

Answer (score 0):

System mandated:

It should NOT appear before the `<asp:ScriptManager>` tag of the page.

Your need:

All parts that you ONLY want to be updated when a certain event is fired should be placed inside the `<ContentTemplate>` tag of the `UpdatePanel`.

Example below:

```
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblDontUpdateMe" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblUpdateMe" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

For your question:

```
<form method="post" id="formLogin" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            // bunch of scriptreferences
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email:"/><br/>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password:"/><br/>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>
            </p>

            <div id="msg" runat="server" class="item">

                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
            </div>

            <div class="loginbutton">
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="forgot">Forgot Password?</a><br />
                    <a href="../EN/form_1.aspx" class="forgot">New user?</a>
                </p>
                <input type="reset" name="login" value="Cancel" id="cancel" />

                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```